# Converting XML to JSON in Python with separated schema

Tags: python, json, xml, lxml, data-conversion

I am looking to convert incoming XML data to JSON to allow for more efficient processing of the data in Python. The XML is of a non-standard format where the schema is defined above the relevant values section (example below).

I am able to read in the schema correctly but am having an issue with creating the correct nesting of tags within the values part of the XML.

Caveats:

- It is possible to have multiples values for all blocks other than Block 1
- Sub-blocks, such as Block 3_1, can be empty and should be represented as an empty list in the JSON

I'm looking to solve the problem in a generalised way (avoiding: for subblock in "Block 3") so it can adapt to small changes in structure/naming convention.

Example XML:

```xml
<body>
    <schema>
        <name>Block 1</name>
        <attributes>
            <string>block_1_attribute_1_name</string>
        </attributes>
        <subblocks>
            <block>
                <name>Block 2</name>
                <attributes>
                    <string>block_2_attribute_1_name</string>
                </attributes>
            </block>
            <block>
                <name>Block 3</name>
                <attributes>
                    <string>block_3_attribute_1_name</string>
                </attributes>
                <subblocks>
                    <block>
                        <name>Block 3_1</name>
                        <attributes>
                            <string>block_3_1_attribute_1_name</string>
                        </attributes>
                    </block>
                </subblocks>
            </block>
        </subblocks>
    </schema>
    <profiles>
        <values>
            <string>block_1_attribute_1_value_1</string>
        </values>
        <subblocks>
            <subblock>
                <values>
                    <string>block_2_attribute_1_value_1</string>
                </values>
            </subblock>
            <subblock>
                <values>
                    <string>block_3_attribute_1_value_1</string>
                </values>
                <subblocks>
                    <subblock>
                        <values>
                            <string>block_3_1_attribute_1_value_1</string>
                        </values>
                    </subblock>
                </subblocks>
            </subblock>
            <subblock>
                <values>
                    <string>block_3_attribute_1_value_2</string>
                </values>
                <subblocks>
                    <subblock>
                        <values>
                            <string>block_3_1_attribute_1_value_2</string>
                        </values>
                    </subblock>
                </subblocks>
            </subblock>
            <subblock>
                <values>
                    <string>block_3_attribute_1_value_3</string>
                </values>
                <subblocks>
                    <!-- empty subblock -->
                    <subblock/>  
                </subblocks>
            </subblock>
        </subblocks>
    </profiles>
</body>
```

Example Output:

```json
{
    "Block 1": {
        "block_1_attribute_1_name": "block_1_attribute_1_value",
        "Block 2": [
            {
                "block_2_attribute_1_name": "block_2_attribute_1_value"
            }
        ],
        "Block 3": [
            {
                "block_3_attribute_1_name": "block_3_attribute_1_value_1",
                "Block 3_1": [
                    {
                        "block_3_1_attribute_1_name": "block_3_1_attribute_1_value_1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "block_3_attribute_1_name": "block_3_attribute_1_value_2",
                "Block 3_1": [
                    {
                        "block_3_1_attribute_1_name": "block_3_1_attribute_1_value_2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "block_3_attribute_1_name": "block_3_attribute_1_value_3",
                "Block 3_1": []
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried writing code that so far gets me the schema. This works but isn't nested (doesn't necessarily have to be). I'm not sure where to start with the rest.

```
def get_schema(root):
    """Retrieves the schema from the XML root element.

    Args:
        root (Element): The root element of the XML string.

    Returns:
        list: A list of tuples representing the schema. Each tuple contains
            the name of a given schema block and a list of attribute names
            associated with that element.
    """
    schema = []
    for name in root.findall(".//name"):
        attribute_names = [elem.text for elem in name.getnext().findall(".//string")]
        schema.append((name.text, attribute_names))
    return schema
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [xmltodict](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) (fetch it with `pip install xmltodict`) to easily convert the XML string to a Python dictionary and then modify its structure if necessary. In a second step, you can convert the modified dictionary to a JSON string if you require it.

There are also other packages like [lxml](https://lxml.de/) to parse XML strings. They may differ in how well they can handle non-standard formats.

Here's an example with `xmltodict`:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

import xmltodict

s = """
<body>
    <schema>
        <name>Block 1</name>
        <attributes>
            <string>block_1_attribute_1_name</string>
        </attributes>
        <subblocks>
            <block>
                <name>Block 2</name>
                <attributes>
                    <string>block_2_attribute_1_name</string>
                </attributes>
            </block>
            <block>
                <name>Block 3</name>
                <attributes>
                    <string>block_3_attribute_1_name</string>
                </attributes>
                <subblocks>
                    <block>
                        <name>Block 3_1</name>
                        <attributes>
                            <string>block_3_1_attribute_1_name</string>
                        </attributes>
                    </block>
                </subblocks>
            </block>
        </subblocks>
    </schema>
    <profiles>
        <values>
            <string>block_1_attribute_1_value_1</string>
        </values>
        <subblocks>
            <subblock>
                <values>
                    <string>block_2_attribute_1_value_1</string>
                </values>
            </subblock>
            <subblock>
                <values>
                    <string>block_3_attribute_1_value_1</string>
                </values>
                <subblocks>
                    <subblock>
                        <values>
                            <string>block_3_1_attribute_1_value_1</string>
                        </values>
                    </subblock>
                </subblocks>
            </subblock>
            <subblock>
                <values>
                    <string>block_3_attribute_1_value_2</string>
                </values>
                <subblocks>
                    <subblock>
                        <values>
                            <string>block_3_1_attribute_1_value_2</string>
                        </values>
                    </subblock>
                </subblocks>
            </subblock>
            <subblock>
                <values>
                    <string>block_3_attribute_1_value_3</string>
                </values>
                <subblocks>
                    <!-- empty subblock -->
                    <subblock/>  
                </subblocks>
            </subblock>
        </subblocks>
    </profiles>
</body>
"""

d = xmltodict.parse(s)
schema = d['body']['schema']
profiles = d['body']['profiles']
schema_json = json.dumps(schema)
profiles_json = json.dumps(profiles)

pprint(schema)
print('='*120)
pprint(schema_json)

print('#'*120)

pprint(profiles)
print('='*120)
pprint(profiles_json)
```

Output:

```
{'attributes': {'string': 'block_1_attribute_1_name'},
 'name': 'Block 1',
 'subblocks': {'block': [{'attributes': {'string': 'block_2_attribute_1_name'},
                          'name': 'Block 2'},
                         {'attributes': {'string': 'block_3_attribute_1_name'},
                          'name': 'Block 3',
                          'subblocks': {'block': {'attributes': {'string': 'block_3_1_attribute_1_name'},
                                                  'name': 'Block 3_1'}}}]}}
========================================================================================================================
('{"name": "Block 1", "attributes": {"string": "block_1_attribute_1_name"}, '
 '"subblocks": {"block": [{"name": "Block 2", "attributes": {"string": '
 '"block_2_attribute_1_name"}}, {"name": "Block 3", "attributes": {"string": '
 '"block_3_attribute_1_name"}, "subblocks": {"block": {"name": "Block 3_1", '
 '"attributes": {"string": "block_3_1_attribute_1_name"}}}}]}}')
########################################################################################################################
{'subblocks': {'subblock': [{'values': {'string': 'block_2_attribute_1_value_1'}},
                            {'subblocks': {'subblock': {'values': {'string': 'block_3_1_attribute_1_value_1'}}},
                             'values': {'string': 'block_3_attribute_1_value_1'}},
                            {'subblocks': {'subblock': {'values': {'string': 'block_3_1_attribute_1_value_2'}}},
                             'values': {'string': 'block_3_attribute_1_value_2'}},
                            {'subblocks': {'subblock': None},
                             'values': {'string': 'block_3_attribute_1_value_3'}}]},
 'values': {'string': 'block_1_attribute_1_value_1'}}
========================================================================================================================
('{"values": {"string": "block_1_attribute_1_value_1"}, "subblocks": '
 '{"subblock": [{"values": {"string": "block_2_attribute_1_value_1"}}, '
 '{"values": {"string": "block_3_attribute_1_value_1"}, "subblocks": '
 '{"subblock": {"values": {"string": "block_3_1_attribute_1_value_1"}}}}, '
 '{"values": {"string": "block_3_attribute_1_value_2"}, "subblocks": '
 '{"subblock": {"values": {"string": "block_3_1_attribute_1_value_2"}}}}, '
 '{"values": {"string": "block_3_attribute_1_value_3"}, "subblocks": '
 '{"subblock": null}}]}}')
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've had a look at xmltodict and the output was similar to what you've shared. I found it doesn't deal with the issue of having to connect the schema to the values.